# RuntimeError: Cannot determine web2py version

Tags: python, runtime-error, web2py

I download and installed web2py 2.5.1 stable on my system, and reading the book I tried to start the application by running `w2p_run` but I got this exception:

```
jorge [~] ~> w2p_run 
WARNING:root:Unable to import plural rules: No module named plural_rules
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/w2p_run", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('web2py==2.5.1-stable-timestamp.2013.06.06.15.39.19', 'w2p_run')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 505, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1245, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web2py-2.5.1_stable_timestamp.2013.06.06.15.39.19-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/w2p_run", line 17, in <module>
    import gluon.widget
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web2py-2.5.1_stable_timestamp.2013.06.06.15.39.19-py2.7.egg/gluon/widget.py", line 25, in <module>
    import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web2py-2.5.1_stable_timestamp.2013.06.06.15.39.19-py2.7.egg/gluon/main.py", line 120, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot determine web2py version")
RuntimeError: Cannot determine web2py version
jorge [~] ~>
```

I really wants to start using web2py, so, Any help? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start web2py with the command:

```
python web2py.py
```

https://github.com/web2py/web2py#installation-instructions

Comment: To start web2py there is **NO NEED to install it.** Just unzip...

Oh, ok, my bad!